# DNS Not Working

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have setup an Ubuntu server with a static IP and I cannot get the DNS to work. Pinging any domain (such as google.com) will not redirect me. I have tried editing /etc/resolv.conf, but that didn't work and it just keeps getting overwritten.

I also tried adding the dns-nameservers x.x.x.x x.x.x.x line to /etc/network/interfaces. I tried this using both my ISP's DNS (obtained it from my Windows desktop with ipconfig) and Google's (8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4), but it still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before anything test that you can actually resolve without configuration setup.

Try the following:

```
#nslookup
>server 8.8.8.8
>google.com
```

if that works make sure that your resolv.conf file contains the following:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

It might be that NetworkManager is running also, and that overrides manual changes

Comment: So this just worked perfectly, thank you very much. Any chance you can explain why this worked, but when I put the following in resolv.conf it failed?

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: can you paste the content of your resolv.conf?

Comment: According to the man page, the preferred format is: _dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4_

Comment: I like the command `getent hosts www.google.com`.  The command `getent` uses the systems way of looking up names.  `nslookup` or ` dig` uses only the DNS system.  Also look up the manual page for `resolvconf`.  That is what is using the `dns-nameserves` directive in `/e/n/interfaces` and other DNS sources to manipulate `/e/resolve.conf`.  So if the package `resolveconf` is installed, never change the contents of `/e/resolv.conf` manually. Use the command.

Comment: careful! replacing the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` (which is a symlink actually) will break the package `resolvconv`. So don't recommend that without further inquirements.

Answer (score 3):

A work around to solve this is to temporarily add the domains you need to the `/etc/hosts` file.

That provided enough connectivity to `sudo aptitude` to resolve the broken dependencies on the system.

After the upgrade, Ubuntu rebooted normally and I could remove the static IPs from the hosts file again.

I used the following to capture the domains I needed to update and put them into a text file:

`sudo apt-get update >> domains.txt`

I used the following to grab the IPs I needed:

```
sh domain-nslookup.sh >> apt-domains.txt
```

The following is the sh file I created and saved as domain-nslookup.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
for DOM in `cat ./apt-domains.txt`;
do
    nslookup $DOM 8.8.8.8 |gawk -F": " '/Address/{print $2}'
    printf "\t%-4s" $DOM
done
printf "\n"
```

After verifying that it worked as planned, I added the IPs and domains to the hosts file:

```
sudo sh domain-nslookup.sh >> hosts
```

Comment: example would not hurt, isn't it?

Comment: edited with example and steps.

Comment: The script didn't quite work for me, but this is a good reminder that while I'm solving my DNS problem, setting up /etc/hosts with what apt wants makes things a lot easier.  Thanks!